# Run animation only when user access the website from the url bar

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to run an animation only when user access the website from the url bar
and not when the route change.

this is my current solution

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from "next/router";

class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      oAni: true
    };
    this.routeChangeEnd = this.routeChangeEnd.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', this.routeChangeEnd);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    Router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', this.routeChangeEnd);
  }
  routeChangeEnd() {
    this.setState({oAni: false});
  }
    render (){
      return (
        <>
          <OpeningAnimation st={this.state.oAni ? "flex" : "none"} aniEnd={()=>{this.setState({oAni: false})}} />

          <div>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
}
```

the `aniEnd` is triggered when the animation end.
but this cause a `memory leak` some times.

What is the best solution to trigger the animation only when the website is accessed from the url bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check if user has done SSR (Server side rendering) in other word refresh the page and typed in the URL bar, you can find out by checking it in `getInitialProps` like this:

```
static async getInitialProps({req}){
  if(req){
  // Called on server
  // Here you can set a variable true
  // Later on on the code if this variable is true, then trigger the animation
  } else {
    // Called on client
  }
 }
```

This is what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, the first time I done so I used `isServer` witch was `undefined` so it haven't worked. as for the memory leak it caused by changing the style of the component with `this.props.st` so I replaced it with `{this.state.oAni ? <OpeningAnimation aniEnd={()=>{this.setState({oAni: false})}} /> : null}`